# Is there any API in Android that measures the Bluetooth signal strength?

Tags: android, bluetooth, signal-strength

Is there any API in Android that measures the Bluetooth signal strength?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This SO post seemed to have a good answer, though the person asking never followed up or voted it. It involves using the native development kit.

[Android 2.1: How do I poll the RSSI value of an existing Bluetooth connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149295/android-2-1-how-do-i-poll-the-rssi-value-of-an-existing-bluetooth-connection)