# Android returning "null" for Bluetooth RSSI

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am developing a android application using Eclipse to return the RSSI values of a Bluetooth device. I have modified the Android Bluetooth Chat example to fit my needs, but I am having problems returning the RSSI value. After hitting the `scan` button to discover nearby devices it returns the device name, device address, and is also suppose to return the RSSI value but instead it says `null` for the RSSI.

```
if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress() + getRssi());

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
           // Get the Bluetooth RSSI
            short Rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
            // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
            // Added getRssi()
            if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress() + getRssi());
            }
        // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            setTitle(R.string.select_device);
            if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but maybe this SO answer will help:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2361630/831918

Supposedly it is possible using the NDK. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am getting RSSI

> String deviceRSSI =
>   (intent.getExtras()).get(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI).toString();

```
private final BroadcastReceiver ActionFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                String deviceRSSI = (intent.getExtras()).get(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI).toString();

                btArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress() + "\n" + deviceRSSI);
                btArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED)) {

            } else if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED)) {

            }
        }
    };
```