# Finding the cartesian coordinates of another smartphone?

Tags: android, iphone, bluetooth, gps, smartphone

Considering I have two smartphones, A and B. If I am holding smartphone A, is there a way to determine the location of B in relation to myself?

So if we had the situation of this image:

[image: cartesian coordinates]:

it would tell me B is at position (2, 1).

Inventive methods like using the strength of wifi signals to get position are more then welcomed. Could I also determine if there is a wall between the two phones?

Comment: No. Unless you are happy with inaccurate GPS locations. Maybe more is possible with a 3rd phone so you can do some triangualtion

Comment: @b2238488: Have u found any solution or any idea on this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, both Bluetooth and Wi-Fi signals move in a radial wave in all directions - so while you may be able to measure the distance between the two terminals, I doubt this would give you a correct reading, since it could either be on your "side" of the circular area or another one equidistant to the source of the signal.

While GPS may be the obvious solution since it provides exactly what you're looking for, I'm not sure if you're including this as an option. Once you get the two coordinate sets for the devices, it's a matter of calculating the offset (N/S and E/W) from device 1.

This makes me think on the accuracy given by GPS, which considering that you were including the tag Bluetooth in the question and since Bluetooth has a range of around 15-30 feet (type 2-3) and the GPS has an error margin of 25-35 feet, this may not be good either.

If you **do** manage to get a connection (Bluetooth) between the two devices, you'd already know your in that range, but not in what direction. You can get a signal strength measure from [Android 2.1: How do I poll the RSSI value of an existing Bluetooth connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149295/android-2-1-how-do-i-poll-the-rssi-value-of-an-existing-bluetooth-connection) but there-again I'm not sure as to how to detect in what direction the user is relative to you, just how close he is, in any direction. Hell the other device could be on top of you or under you and you'd get virtually the same reading as next to you given equal distances.

This is all on a "static" approach, meaning both devices are stationary. However if you measure that value and then take a step to your left and re-measure you can tell if you're closer or further away from the source, so with a little trial and error of one of the devices moving you could determine a relative position, this however may not be useful for you since you'd either need to tell the phone manually that you moved left and to re-measure or use something more complicated like monitoring the accelerometer of the phone which could tell in what direction the phone moved and map the strength of the signal.

Am I losing my mind? **Probably**.

No answer as far as I'm concerned for now, just thoughts. Depending on what the application will do, there may be other viable approaches. This is my brain-dump answer so hopefully someone else can read it and come up with a more elaborate answer instead of rumbling thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

If the distance from A to B is more than a few metres, then if you can get the GPS location of both A & B, you can easily calculate distance and bearing between them using the Location.distanceTo() and Location.bearingTo() methods.

Depending on the physical environment, it is probable that two GPSs which are physically close together will be using the same satellites for calculation, and that the errors will be similar in both. So in some cases using GPS may work for small distances.