# Locate Bluetooth in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, locate

I have code bluetooth service (It can sent and received data file), Now I want development it, I want to locate of all bluetooth client conect to my service which similar bluetooth radar.

I need android document.
Please share document or source code help me.

Thanks.

Comment: did u read "http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html" ?

Comment: Yes I had read, but I don't know how do determine location of all client,  I only show client name, I want make it same to radar, coordinates, left, right, above, below on screen. Thank you reply.

Comment: check this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542857/finding-the-cartesian-coordinates-of-another-smartphone

Comment: Thank You, I understand, use to Location.distanceTo()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From android doc site :

**Public Methods :**

```
distanceTo(Location dest)
```

Returns the approximate distance in meters between this location and the given location.