# BlueZ Bluetooth API and distance calibration precision

Tags: c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I am using BlueZ C API to program my bluetooth mouse to read the distance. I have set up a bluetooth dongle. At the moment, I have to move the mouse at least 5-10 feet from the laptop (bluetooth dongle) to get some reading of RSSI. Below this distance, I get most of the readings as 0.

Is there any way to use this API to get more precise value of RSSI so that we can track the distance in this range?

```
int8_t Bluetooth::read_rssi(int to) {

    int dd = hciSocket;
    struct hci_conn_info_req *cr;
    bdaddr_t bdaddr;
    int8_t rssi;

    str2ba(bt_addr, &bdaddr);

    if (dd < 0) {
            perror("HCI device open failed");
            exit(1);
    }   

    cr = (hci_conn_info_req *)(malloc(sizeof(*cr) + sizeof(struct hci_conn_info)));
    if (!cr) {
            perror("Can't allocate memory");
            exit(1);
    }   

    bacpy(&cr->bdaddr, &bdaddr);
    cr->type = ACL_LINK;
    if (ioctl(dd, HCIGETCONNINFO, (unsigned long) cr) < 0) {
            perror("Get connection info failed");
            exit(1);
    }   

    if (hci_read_rssi(dd, htobs(cr->conn_info->handle), &rssi, 1000) < 0) {
            perror("Read RSSI failed");
            exit(1);
    }   

    return rssi;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hci_read_rssi` is probably not what you want. It's not the actual remote RSSI. From the BT spec section describing the HCI_Read_RSSI command:

> The RSSI parameter returns the difference between the measured
>   Received Signal Strength Indication (RSSI) and the limits of the
>   Golden Receive Power Range for a Connection Handle to another BR/EDR
>   Controller. Any positive RSSI value returned by the Controller
>   indicates how many dB the RSSI is above the upper limit, any negative
>   value indicates how many dB the RSSI is below the lower limit. The
>   value zero indicates that the RSSI is inside the Golden Receive Power
>   Range.

I believe the value you want is the one contained in the inquiry/scan. I know of a way to get that but not sure whether it's acceptable to you or whether it is the best way.

The bluez dbus device API has RSSI as one of the properties. The api doc can be found [here](https://github.com/r10r/bluez/blob/master/doc/device-api.txt).

UPDATE: I haven't tried it myself but looks like pybluez supports getting the inquiry RSSI. See [this pybluez example](https://pybluez.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/advanced/inquiry-with-rssi.py).

Here's a simple example for bluez4:

https://bitbucket.org/kaylum/bluez-rssi-example/src

Comment: Do you have any code examples of the getting the RSSI value from the inquiry/scan based API? Can you please share more details?

Comment: What version of Bluez are you using? I don't have a standalone example to share at this time. But it won't take me long to write a basic example. I'll update the answer in a day or so with a link to the code. But note that I use glib's dbus binding so you will need to have that library installed. If that's not acceptable let me know now so I don't spend time on it.

Comment: I am using 4.101 Bluez version on Ubuntu 14.04. TBH, I am completely new, and whatever I have understood is through available open examples. Right now, I have written a c++ class from the available example (also posted in the original post). So, I believe, it should be fine to have glib /dbus binding, as long as it allows me to update my current c++ class. Thank you for help.

Comment: What version is your Bluez? I'm using 5. I ask because there were significant dbus api changes between 4 and 5. So I want to be sure the example will work for your environment.

Comment: I am using 4.101 version of bluez.

Comment: Did you get chance to work out a sample example code @Alan Au?

Comment: @AnilJ Apologies for the long delay. I've update the answer with a link to a simple example. Usage: `./rssi <bt_address>`. It will just keep reading and printing the remote device's rssi until the program is killed. It's a bit rough but should give you the general idea.

Comment: Did you have any idea with bluez5 for raspberry Pi?

Comment: @ZuzooVn The technique is the same for bluez5. Just slightly different APIs. Please post a new question if you have specific difficulties are something you don't understand (hard to answer in comments).