# how to find rssi and distance using bluez api in linux

Tags: c++, linux, distance, bluez, rssi

I am trying to get distance from a bluetooth device using rssi parameters of Bluez Api. I have downloaded a code from internet and running it. The error uggests me that method "DefaultAdapter" is missing. But I do not know the signature of this method. May be there i some other error alo. I am pasting my code below:
Any other simpler code link is good.
I get error
Unable to get managed objects: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "DefaultAdapter" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.Manager" doesn't exist, getting distance through rssi using bluez apis

```
pthread_t threadId;
#define BLUEZ_BUS_NAME "org.bluez"
#define BLUEZ_INTF_ADAPTER "org.bluez.Adapter"

static GDBusConnection *dbus_conn = NULL;
static GMainLoop *main_loop;


struct handler_data {
  const char *bt_address;
  short rssi;
};

/*
 * Callback function for the DeviceFound signal from the org.bluez.Adapter
 * interface.
 */
static void
device_found_handler (GDBusConnection *connection,
                        const gchar *sender_name,
                        const gchar *object_path,
                        const gchar *interface_name,
                        const gchar *signal_name,
                        GVariant *parameters,
                        gpointer user_data)
{
  char *device_address;
  gboolean res;
  short rssi;
  GVariant *property_dict;
  struct handler_data *data = (struct handler_data *)user_data;

  /*
   * Paramter format: sa{sv}
   * Only interested in the RSSI so lookup that entry in the properties
   * dictionary.
   */
  g_variant_get(parameters, "(&s*)", &device_address, &property_dict);

  if (strcmp(data->bt_address, device_address)) {
    /* Not the device of interest */
    return;
  }

  res = g_variant_lookup(property_dict, "RSSI", "n",
                         &rssi);
  if (!res) {
    printf("Unable to get device address from dbus\n");

  g_main_loop_quit(main_loop);
    return;
  }

  data->rssi = rssi;
  g_main_loop_quit(main_loop);
}

/*
 * Gets the RSSI for a given BT device address.
 */
static short
get_rssi(const char *bt_address)
{
  GError *error = NULL;
  GVariant *reply = NULL;
  char *adapter_object = NULL;
  struct handler_data data;

  data.bt_address = bt_address;

  main_loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
  if (!main_loop) {
    printf("Error creating main loop\n");
    return 0;
  }

  dbus_conn = g_bus_get_sync(G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM, NULL, &error);
  if (error) {
    printf("Unable to get dbus connection\n");
    return 0;
  }

  /* Get the default BT adapter. Needed to start device discovery */
  reply = g_dbus_connection_call_sync(dbus_conn,
                                      BLUEZ_BUS_NAME,
                                      "/",
                                      "org.bluez.Manager",
                                      "DefaultAdapter",
                                      NULL,
                                      G_VARIANT_TYPE("(o)"),
                                      G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE,
                                      -1,
                                      NULL,
                                      &error);

  if (error) {
    printf("Unable to get managed objects: %s\n", error->message);
    return 0;
  }
  g_variant_get(reply, "(&o)", &adapter_object);

  /* Register a handler for DeviceFound signals to read the device RSSI */
  g_dbus_connection_signal_subscribe(dbus_conn,
                                     NULL,
                                     "org.bluez.Adapter",
                                     "DeviceFound",
                                     NULL,
                                     NULL,
                                     /*0*/G_DBUS_SIGNAL_FLAGS_NONE,
                                     device_found_handler,
                                     &data,
                                     NULL);

  /* Start device discovery */
  reply = g_dbus_connection_call_sync(dbus_conn,
                                     BLUEZ_BUS_NAME,
                                     adapter_object,
                                     "org.bluez.Adapter",
                                     "StartDiscovery",
                                     NULL,
                                     NULL,
                                     G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE,
                                     -1,
                                     NULL,
                                     &error);

  if (error) {
    printf("Unable to start discovery: %s\n", error->message);
    return 0;
  }

  g_main_loop_run(main_loop);

  return data.rssi;
}










void* getSetDeviceDetails(void * arg)
{

    char* destinationAddress = new char[strlen((char*)arg)+1];
    strcpy(destinationAddress, (char*)arg);
short rssi = 0;
rssi = get_rssi(destinationAddress);
cout<< "rssi=" << rssi<< endl;

}


void scanDevices(inquiry_info **ii, int * sock, int * num_rsp)
{
    int max_rsp;
    int dev_id, len, flags;
    int i;

    dev_id = hci_get_route(NULL);
    *sock = hci_open_dev( dev_id );
    if (dev_id < 0 || sock < 0) {
        perror("opening socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    len  = 8;
    max_rsp = 255;
    flags = IREQ_CACHE_FLUSH;
    *ii = (inquiry_info*)malloc(max_rsp * sizeof(inquiry_info));

    *num_rsp = hci_inquiry(dev_id, len, max_rsp, NULL, ii, flags);
    if( num_rsp < 0 ) perror("hci_inquiry");
    printf("num devices = %d\n",*num_rsp);

}



int main()
{
inquiry_info *ii = NULL;
    int  num_rsp, i, sock;
    char addr[19] = { 0 };
    char name[248] = { 0 };
    scanDevices(&ii, &sock, &num_rsp);

    close( sock );
    char destinationAddress[18];
                ba2str(&(ii)->bdaddr, destinationAddress);
                cout<<destinationAddress<<"print"<<endl;
                pthread_create(&threadId,0,getSetDeviceDetails,(void*)destinationAddress);
                pthread_join(threadId,0);
    free( ii );
}
```

I got another code from internet. It had some problem as was originally posted. But the person had written that he was not making connection to server before ioctl. He corrected it and it worked.
I downloaded his code and getting the same problem.
the link to that is
https://communities.intel.com/thread/100186

can someone suggest anything.

Comment: "DefaultAdapter" is in outdated bluez4.x version. What is the version of BlueZ which you are using?

Comment: The below URL's may help you" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025139/bluez-bluetooth-api-and-distance-calibration-precision https://bitbucket.org/kaylum/bluez-rssi-example/src/3bf009da0552f46c19fdf791f79ed263bb552989/main.c?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: I'm getting this error as well. I ran the code in the second link you posted, @Parthiban, and that's actually why I'm here. What was DefaultAdapter replaced by?

Comment: There is no default adapter in Bluez5. It's upto application to name it as default. We GAP profile directly integrated into bluez5 using Adapter API which provides methods to connect the device. You have to listen on PropertiesChanged signal on the interested device for RSSI value. This value is dynamically emitted by bluez on DBus. @GiselleSerate

Comment: Adding to that, you can find few examples written using bluez5 DBus interface in my gist https://gist.github.com/parthitce and its theoretical explanation here https://www.linumiz.com. But examples and blog are still incomplete.

Comment: Thanks @Parthiban! I was able to make your scan program work, but your connect program gave me an Invalid Arguments error: `Unable to get result: GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.InvalidArguments: Invalid arguments in method call`. Was something you'd run across previously? Would you know which method call it might be talking about? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: What's your Bluez version? ConnectDevice call may be still experimental, so you need to run `bluetoothd -E`

Comment: It was unable to find ConnectDevice on bluez 5.43, so I updated bluez to 5.49 and it stopped having problems finding that particular function, especially after I made it run with the `-E` flag. I will look into the actual parameters of ConnectDevice, though, perhaps there's an API discrepancy? @Parthiban

Comment: You can find the details about the API here https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt#n154 but not sure whether it's still experimental in latest release or not. But this should work without any problems.